# Stored procedure returns multiple temp table results. I want to copy them into one CSV file using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, script-task

I have a stored procedure that has multiple select statements using temp tables. I want to copy the results into one CSV file. Each result has different columns. I would like to copy them in such a way that each result set should leave two lines of space in CSV file.

Example below :

[image]

Sample stored procedure

```
Create procedure usp_Test_CSV_Report
As
Begin
    select 'Text Sample' as Description, 123 Amount, 20210511 as Joindate
    select GETDATE() as MonthATB
    select 1 as AccountId, 'CI' as Name
    select 'Sample Report'
End
```

The temp tables have been created within the stored procedure which will be called like `Select * from #temp`. I have not included real stored procedure which is vast.

I will be running the stored procedure using C#

```
string query = "EXEC alpha.dbo.usp_Test_CSV_Report";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, SQLConnection);

SQLConnection.Open();

DataTable d_table = new DataTable();
SqlDataReader sqlReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    d_table.Load(sqlReader);
                    // Write the Header Row to File
                    int ColumnCount = d_table.Columns.Count;
                    for (int ic = 0; ic < ColumnCount; ic++)
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show(d_table.Columns[ic].ToString());
                        sw.Write(d_table.Columns[ic]);
                        if (ic < ColumnCount - 1)
                        {
                            sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                        }
                    }
                    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                    // Write All Rows to the File
                    foreach (DataRow dr in d_table.Rows)
                    {
                        for (int ir = 0; ir < ColumnCount; ir++)
                        {
                            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))
                            {
                                sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());
                                //MessageBox.Show(dr[ir].ToString());
                            }
                            if (ir < ColumnCount - 1)
                            {
                                sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                            }
                        }
                        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                    }

                  
            }

            sqlReader.NextResult();

            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                d_table.Load(sqlReader);
                // Write the Header Row to File
                int ColumnCount = d_table.Columns.Count;
                for (int ic = 0; ic < ColumnCount; ic++)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(d_table.Columns[ic].ToString());
                    sw.Write(d_table.Columns[ic]);
                    if (ic < ColumnCount - 1)
                    {
                        sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                    }
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                // Write All Rows to the File
                foreach (DataRow dr in d_table.Rows)
                {
                    for (int ir = 0; ir < ColumnCount; ir++)
                    {
                        if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))
                        {
                            sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());
                            //MessageBox.Show(dr[ir].ToString());
                        }
                        if (ir < ColumnCount - 1)
                        {
                            sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                        }
                    }
                    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                }

               
            }

                SQLConnection.Close();
            sw.Close();
```

So far I have tried this but this is not working!!
Any help?

Comment: Rather than CSV... have you considered XML or JSON ?

Comment: It is unclear what "has multiple Temp table results" means.  Also, how are you running these stored procedures?  If you mean that the stored procedure create their own Temp tables, then these will be deleted when the procedure exits.  If you mean that the sql session creates the temp tables and then the sprocs fill them in, then you would still at least need to be holding that session connection open in your code.  If by Temp tables you really mean an output table-valued parameter or function, or the output stream of SELECTs, then we would still need to see the code that doing this.

Comment: CSV is a brain dead simple format. It's a set of rows, typically separated by newlines, each row containing an ordered set of values, separated by a delimiter (typically a comma). You can optionally add a header row. But, there is no guiding standard, you really can do what you want, as long as the reader and the writer agree. Don't expect much library help if you deviate too much from normal. In your case, what you want is probably doable if you separate the chunks of CSV data into streams to be individually deserialized (and, when serializing, you do it in chunks later concatenated together)

Comment: Open a StreamWriter and write lines one at time.  You can uses String.Join(",", object[]); to create CSV.  The use writer.Writeline() to write the sata.

Comment: I'm kind of not into coding. I have this scenario to run on SQL Server using SSIS package Script Task.

Comment: You _can_ do it, but should you? I agree with @Flydog57. One table per CSV file is the norm unless you are going to write a custom parser.

Comment: I tried it using the SqlDataReader and data table but not able to copy the data into CSV.

Comment: CSV is simple, until you need to handle values that contain commas or newlines. String.Join(",", ...) will eventually bite you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maintain a nuget package, [Sylvan.Data.Csv](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sylvan.Data.Csv/1.0.1), that makes this very easy.

```
    string query = "EXEC alpha.dbo.usp_Test_CSV_Report";

    using SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection();
    conn.Open();
    using SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    using var sw = File.CreateText("usp_Test_CSV_Report.csv");
    using var csvWriter = CsvDataWriter.Create(sw);
    using var sqlReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    bool first = true;
    do
    {
        if (!first)
        {
            // write the two lines to separate the result sets.
            sw.WriteLine();
            sw.WriteLine();
        }
        first = false;
        csvWriter.Write(sqlReader);
    } while (sqlReader.NextResult());
```

The library also supports reading multiple result sets out of a single CSV in much the same way:

```
    // tell the reader to expect multiple result sets.
    var csvOpts = new CsvDataReaderOptions { ResultSetMode = ResultSetMode.MultiResult };
    var csvReader = CsvDataReader.Create("usp_Test_CSV_Report.csv", csvOpts);
    do
    {
        while (csvReader.Read())
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < csvReader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                var value = csvReader.GetString(i);
            }
        }
    } while (csvReader.NextResult());
```

Comment: I like the solution. but I'm not able to use nuggets inside SSIS. is there any alternative to it. Thanks

Comment: It's open source, so you could go copy all of the source code into your project: https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan. Not ideal, but it should work.

Comment: Okay, @MarkPflug Thank you. I will try to implement it.